# (Discord api) Change nickname on a server with python requests

Tags: python, python-requests, discord, discord.py

I am trying to change the nickname of my account on a website but it's not working. This is the code I used.

```
import requests
token=input('Enter your token: ')
payload = {
            'nick': 'new nickname'
            }
headers = {
    'authorization': token
    }
r = requests.patch('https://discord.com/api/v9/guilds/8652577727676008/members/@me', data=payload, headers=headers)
```

[request method and url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwXaS.jpg)   |  [authorization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkxXy.jpg)     |  [data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRuqS.jpg)

Comment: What's' your question here exactly?

Comment: I tried using this code which didn't work. It seems correct to me. Any help? I'd like to change my nickname on a server.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import requests, json
token=input('Enter your token: ')
payload = {
            "nick": "tester"
            }
headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bot {token}",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }

r = requests.patch('https://discord.com/api/v9/guilds/8652577727676008/members/@me', data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)

print(r.content)
```

I'm new in apis too. But the mistakes you've made are:

### Headers

- The authorization should be `Bot {token}` not just `{token}` (in case
  of bots)
- You have not defined the content type

### Data

- Making the data a json string instead of a dict object worked for me